# Issue with RedirectAction

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a `FormController` with `Index` action and `SimpleController` with `CorticonIndex` action.

I am redirecting to `CorticonIndex` from `Index` action. My problem is, I have put a breakpoint at return `RedirectToAction()` and `CorticonIndex()`.

So,Only for the first time I can see the execution by F11 but for the second time controller is not going to `CorticonIndex()`.

How the `RedirectToAction()` will work?

Is it only one time execution or can we execute multiple time??

FormController

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formCollection)
{
    return RedirectToAction("CorticonIndex", " SimpleController");
}
```

SimpleController

```
public ActionResult CorticonIndex()
{
    var viewModel = this.Model.GetViewModel(payLoad);
    return View(CorticonResponseModel.viewName, viewModel);
}
```

Comment: Every time you submit to `Index()` it will redirect to `CorticonIndex()`

Comment: Hi Stephen, It has to redirect everytime I click submit but I am unable to debug as it is not navigating to redirected action.

Comment: Then I can only assume you view is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> How the RedirectToAction() will work?

It sends an HTTP 302 response to the browser of the web site along with a [`Location` header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302). What the browser does with that is up to the browser. Normally, it will use the `Location` header to submit another request to your server. But, as this is entirely out of the application's control, there are no guarantees.

But in this case you are initially calling the server using an HTTP POST. If your browser reloads the page using an HTTP GET, it will not hit this same action method. If you have an HTTP GET action method named `Index`, it will call that one instead.

> **NOTE:** FYI - if you remove the `HttpPost` attribute, your action method will respond to both GET and POST. But that is probably not the solution to your issue, as it is normal to have a separate action method in each case.